# How to track re-entries of a contact into a Marketing Cloud journey

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I can't quite solve this one. I'm building a few gated content journeys in Marketing Cloud's Journey Builder to deliver free downloads, followed by a couple more emails. I want to allow re-entry (after exiting) for people who want the content again (lost it or forgot about requesting it, etc.). But I want to track re-entries. My usual process is a DateCompleted column in the associated data extension that gets updated just before exiting the journey, but I don't want to overwrite this value when a person re-enters the journey.

I can think of two desirable alternative outcomes:

1. Add the DateCompleted date, and append a new date for each re-entry.
2. Iterate a count of entries in a Completed column with each entry, telling me how many times a single contact has completed the journey.

As I've explored the Journey Builder actions, I can't come up with a way to accomplish either alternative. ***Is this even possible?*** Surely I'm not the only person to want this out of Marketing Cloud.

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [journeybuilder](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journeybuilder) tags.